# Get greater (subquery ) list than the AVG (subquery) in SQLite3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, relational-database

consider the following table:

```
    covid_data(
        CASES               INT,
        DEATHS              INT,
        COUNTRIES           VARCHAR(64),
    );
```

I am trying to get the names of the countries which the mortality rate is greater than the AVG mortality rate. The formula I am using to get the number of deaths based on every 1000 cases is:
         (NUMBER OF DEATHS / NUMBER OF CASES) * 1000
To get the AVG I use this query:

```
    SELECT AVG(rate)
    FROM (
          SELECT CAST(SUM(deaths) AS FLOAT) / SUM(cases) * 1000  AS rate
          FROM covid_data
    ) covid_data;
```

To list the countries with a greater rate than this AVG this is one of the many attempts I have tried so far.

```
SELECT countries, CAST(SUM(deaths) AS FLOAT) / SUM(cases) * 1000 AS RATEM
FROM covid_data
GROUP BY countries
HAVING RATEM > (SELECT AVG(RATE)
FROM (
      SELECT CAST(SUM(DEATHS) AS FLOAT) / SUM(CASES) * 1000  AS RATE
      FROM covid_data
     ) covid_data);
```

This is returning an error: no such column: RATEM

As you can see I am struggling with this basic concepts I would appreciate as well any books/courses/resources to better understand this relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT cd.country
FROM (SELECT cd.*, 
             SUM(deaths * 1.0) OVER () / SUM(cases) OVER () as mortality_ratio
      FROM covid_data
     ) cd
WHERE (deaths * 1.0 / NULLIF(cases, 0)) > mortality_ratio;
```

Note that the average of the  mortality ratio in each country is NOT the same as the overall mortality ratio.  I think you understand this but I just want to emphasize that point.  The average ratio would be:

```
AVG(deaths * 1.0 / NULLIF(cases, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (
    select
        t.*,
        1.0 * deaths / cases rate,
        1.0 * sum(deaths) over() / sum(cases) over() avg_rate
    from covid_date
) t
where rate > avg_rate
```